# p:dataTable select single row using radioButton & single row select

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable

im using primefaces, come from this [Post](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=44121) without answer.
Is it possible to select data from a row with RadioButton and also select by clicking on the row?
when testing this code it works but RadioButton click didn't work

```html
<p:dataTable id="dato" value="#{aGuiaBean.listUsuario}" var="data"   
  selectionMode="single"  selection="#{aGuiaBean.usuarioSeleccionado}"
  rowKey="#{data.idUsuario}"   >
  <p:column  selectionMode="single" />
</p:dataTable>
```

And this way it only works by clicking on RadioButton and not on the row of the datatable

```html
<p:dataTable id="dato" value="#{aGuiaBean.listUsuario}" var="data"   
   selection="#{aGuiaBean.usuarioSeleccionado}"
  rowKey="#{data.idUsuario}"   >
  <p:column  selectionMode="single" />
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Can you specify your Primefaces version?

Comment: THE VERSION DE PRIMEFACES IS PRIMEFACES 8.0

Answer (score 1):

This does not work out of the box and there is an open PrimeFaces ticket about the issue:

**Issue**: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4468

**PR**: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/6090

The PR fixes it for 9.0